# Script won't work properly-- new to scripting

Tags: scripting

I am trying to write a script that accepts one parameter that contains a directory name and check to see if it exits.  The name of the script should be: script_practice_3.sh and pass blc to the script.  For example: ./script_practice_3.sh blc

For some reason, my script does not work and i do not know why. I am knew to unix script writing and it is really frustrating me.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "What is the parameter name that contains the script name: "
read SCRIPT

echo "What is the parameter name that contains the value blc: "
read VALUE

if [ "$?" = "0" ]
then
 echo "You must provide one parameter"
elif [ "$?" > "1" ]
then
 echo "You must provide only one parameter"
else
 test -d $SCRIPT
 if [ "$?" = "0" ]
 then
  echo "Already exists"
 else
 mkdir $VALUE
 echo "directory created"
fi
```

Comment: why is your script written to accept manual inputs?

Comment: I'm practicing with script writing so i thought this was a good place to start

Comment: are you saying that you did not write that script?

Comment: no i definitely wrote it, im not understanding your first question

Answer (score 1):

The special variable `$?` is the *exit status* of the most recently run command.  The number of arguments given to the script (the number of positional parameters) is given by `$#`.

You can't use `>` to compare whether a value is numerically larger than another.  For that, use `-gt`.  The `>` test is a test for determining the sort order of strings ("`b` sort after `a`, so `"b" > "a"`").

You also lack a `]` on one of the tests.

I'm also uncertain why you read two values interactively if you are expecting the script to be given a single argument on its command line.

Suggestion:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
   echo need exactly one argument >&2
   exit 1
elif [ -d "$1" ]; then
   printf '"%s" is already a directory\n' "$1" >&2
   exit 1
elif ! mkdir "$1"; then
   printf 'failed to create directory "%s"\n' "$1" >&2
   exit 1
fi

printf 'Successfully created directory "%s"\n' "$1"
```

The `$1` that is use throughout this script is the first positional parameter (the first argument given to the script).

The middle test here is actually not needed as `mkdir` (without its `-p` option) would complain if trying to create an already existing directory, so this would be caught by the last test.

This script would be invoked as you propose in the question,

```
./script.sh "some directory name"
```